# SQL SUM issues with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I got a quite complex query (at least for me).
I want to create a list of users that are ready to be paid. There are 2 conditions that need to be met: order status should be 3 and the total should be more then 50. Currently I got this query (generated with Codeingiter active record):

```
SELECT `services_payments`.`consultant_id`
     , `consultant_userdata`.`iban`
     , `consultant_userdata`.`kvk`, `consultant_userdata`.`bic`
     , `consultant_userdata`.`bankname`
     , SUM(`services_payments`.`amount`) AS amount
  FROM (`services_payments`)
  JOIN `consultant_userdata`
    ON `consultant_userdata`.`user_id` = `services_payments`.`consultant_id`
  JOIN `services`
    ON `services`.`id` =  `services_payments`.`service_id`
 WHERE `services`.`status` =  3
   AND `services_payments`.`paid` =  0
HAVING `amount` > 50
```

The services_payments table contains the commissions, consultant_userdata contains the userdata and services keeps the order data. The current query only gives me 1 result while I'm expecting 4 results.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what would be the solution?

Comment: You are missing at least a `GROUP BY services_payments.consultant_id, consultant_userdata.iban, consultant_userdata.kvk, consultant_userdata.bic, consultant_userdata.bankname`

Comment: @rsanchez - you should submit this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ActiveRecord, rsanchez' answer would be more of

```
$this->db->group_by('services_payments.consultant_id, consultant_userdata.iban, consultant_userdata.kvk, consultant_userdata.bic, consultant_userdata.bankname');
```